# ForkJoin Observables from http.get

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular2-observables, fork-join

I've got various points with times that I'm getting with a lot of `http.get` calls.
I need to put them all in the array and print in the grid:

this is how I do that:

when user enters `interval`:

```
ngOnChanges() {
if (this.interval) {

  for (let id of this.ids) {
    this.loadData(id);
  }
}
this.initializeCols();
```

}

I call `loadData(id);` method which uses ForkJoin to create data:

```
  private loadData(id: string) {
let url = DataService.url+ '/data/' + id + '/points';

// Generate API requests
let observables = [];
observables.push(this.http.get(url, DataService.contentTypeJsonHeaders).map(r => r.json()));

// const myPromise = val =>
// new Promise(resolve =>
//   setTimeout(() => resolve(`Promise Resolved: ${val}`), 10000)
// );

// of(observables).pipe(mergeMap(q => forkJoin(...q.map(myPromise)))).subscribe(
//   val => this.model.push(val));

Observable.forkJoin(observables).subscribe((response: any[]) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    let dataArray: Datapoints[] = ArrayFlattener.Inflate(response[i].data);
    for (let d of dataArray) {
      const temp = {
        id: id,
        time: d.time,
        value: d.value,
        originalTime: d.time,
        originalValue: d.value,
        interval: d.interval,
        metric: DataService.GetById(stream.metricId).name
      };
      this.model.push(temp);
    }
  }
});
```

}

But I can't manage to wait until the `model` is filled with data completely and then print it to the grid. I've left  some commented out code in `loadData()` method with my other try. The problem is I don't see model data in the grid unless I click 'add new` button or something so it would make another call, because it should fill grid only when all calls are complete. What I'm doing wrong with my ForkJoin?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass the observables as a single array arguement but multiple arguements instead.

Try using `spread operator` : `Observable.forkJoin(...observables)`

Comment: It did not help though :(